# sql query to fetch data from 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have below table structure.

```
master table >
    m_id, pk
    m_name,
    p_id, fk
    s_id, fk
    t_id, fk
    x_id fk

p table >
    p_id, pk
    p_name

s table >
    s_id, pk
    s_name

t table >
    t_id, pk
    t_name

x table >
    x_id, pk
    x_name
```

I want to get m_id, m_name, p_name, s_name, t_name, x_name for given m_id.

I am applying inner join in the query

```
SELECT mt.m_id, mt.m_name, pt.p_name, st.s_name, tt.t_name, xt.x_name
FROM master mt
    INNER JOIN p AS pt ON pt.p_id = mt.p_id
    INNER JOIN s AS st ON st.s_id = mt.s_id
    INNER JOIN t AS tt ON tt.t_id = mt.t_id
    INNER JOIN x AS xt ON xt.x_id = mt.x_id
WHERE mt.m_id = 50;
```

**Question**: Is there any other efficient way to achieve this or my query is ok?

Thanks.

Comment: Your query is fine.

Comment: Your query is absolutely OK.

Comment: The query looks fine. You might gain by indexes  on the keys  if you are looking for performance.

Comment: Thank you. How do I close this question?

Comment: Note that your solution assumes that values exist for all foreign key columns.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, to ensure that result come even if value does not exist, i will replace inner join with right join in the query.

Comment: @NamanGala, use LEFT JOIN since the first table in your join chain is the main table!

Comment: @jarlh, I think it depends on the join equation, rather then the order of table name. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well, "... a left join b on..." will return the joined rows plus rows from a that do not have any match in b. Rows from b without match in a will not be returned. That's why I recommend "main-table left join other-table", easy to understand and remember!

Comment: @jarlh, got your point.

Comment: @NamanGala Logic requires that for every LEFT JOIN, there must be a semantically equivalent RIGHT JOIN. However, because (I suspect) LEFT JOINs are so much more intuitive, RIGHT JOINs are almost never used. Just see how many results are returned when you search under the mysql tag for LEFT JOIN as opposed to RIGHT JOIN!

Comment: @Strawberry, will check it out and post it here.